# Several independent jquery tickers at one page

Tags: jquery

I intend to use this simple ticker concept in my project, [shown on jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jxc38/3/).

This ticker is okay, but I intend to use bunch of (this) tickers at one page at once, as they gonna be automatically generated by PHP.

There can be 3 of those tickers at once at one page, all the way up to 20, with different content of course.

How can I get them all working, "moving" fine as the first one, using featured HTML?

ps: *pause on hover* added will be such a plus, thx!

**JS**

```
function tick(){
    $('#ticker li:first').slideUp( function () { $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown(); });
}
setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 5000);
```

**HTML**

```
<div><ul class="ticker" id="ticker">
    <li>
        One.
    </li>
    <li>
        Two.
    </li>
    </ul></div>

<div><ul class="ticker" id="ticker1">
    <li>
        3.
    </li>
    <li>
        4.
    </li>
    </ul></div>

<div><ul class="ticker" id="ticker2">
    <li>
        Five.
    </li>
    <li>
        Six.
    </li>
    </ul></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ticker {
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#c1c1c1;
}
.ticker li {
    height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only targeting the first `li` in the set, the whole set. You need to loop through each ticker and then do you're animation on each `li:first`. Append it to the `closest()` ticker and you're good:

```
function tick(){
    $('.ticker').each(function(){
        $(this).find('li:first').slideUp(function () {
            $ticker = $(this).closest('.ticker');
            $(this).appendTo($ticker).slideDown();
        });
    });
}
setInterval(tick, 5000);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gpr9t/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I like oGeez answer better than my own (this really should be a comment rather than editing my answer like this, but I don't have ability to comment yet...).

I would point out, though, that you should be able to add functionality to pause elements when mouse is over them using jquery hover() method to append a class to the element being moused over. http://api.jquery.com/hover/ From there you simply don't include tickers with the paused class in the list of tickers you will update.

```
function tick(){
    $('.ticker').not(".paused").each(function(){
        $(this).find('li:first').slideUp(function () {
            $ticker = $(this).closest('.ticker');
            $(this).appendTo($ticker).slideDown();
        });
    });
}
setInterval(tick, 5000);

$(".ticker").hover(     
    (function () {          
        $(this).addClass("paused")      
    }),      
    (function () {          
        $(this).removeClass("paused")      
    }) 
);
```

I updated my fork of your jsfiddle to reflect oGeez's answer with the ability to pause by mousing over a ticker. http://jsfiddle.net/4MgZv/3/